# What is "Unresolved compilation problem" about?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just started study java and vsc.
I aleardy searched and saw all of questions that have 'Unresolved compilation problem:'.
But I can't find my question.

This is my error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        name cannot be resolved or is not a field

        at Student.<init>(Student.java:10)
        at ShowTrans.main(ShowTrans.java:3)
```

I installed all the extends, debugging programs.

```
Student class

    public class Student {

    String studentName;
    int money;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, int money) {
        this.name = studentName;
        this.money = money;
    }

    public void takeBus(Bus bus) {
        bus.take(1000);
        money -= 1000;
    }

    public void takeSubway(Subway subway) {
        subway.take(1500);
        money -= 1500;
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println(studentName + "left money : " + money");
    }
}
```

Bus class

```
public class Bus {
int money;
int busNumber;
int passenger = 0;

public Bus() {
}

public Bus(int num) {
    this.num = busNumber;
}

public void take(int money) {
    this.money += money;
    passenger++;
}

public void showInfo() {
    System.out.println("Bus" + busNumber + "'s passenger is" + passenger + ", money is" + money");
}}

ShowTrans class

public class ShowTrans {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student james = new Student("James", 10000);

    Bus bus100 = new Bus(100);
    james.takeBus(bus100);
    james.showInfo();
    bus100.showInfo();
}}
```

Comment: You mixed the names. Change `this.name = studentName;` to `this.studentName = name;`

Answer (score 3):

> I just started study java and vsc. I aleardy searched and saw all of questions that have `Unresolved compilation problem`

That means: most likely, you clicked the **run** button in your IDE although your IDE was showing you compilation errors.

In your case, there is a simple typo: you renamed something called `name` to `studentName`, most likely.

To be precise: you got it backwards here:

```
this.name = studentName;
```

that should be

```
this.studentName = name;
```

So, again: you asked your IDE to run code that (due to some change) is inconsistent.

The solution:

- avoid doing that
- meaning: when making changes, make sure that your whole project compiles error-free before doing anything else

Beyond that, learn to use the features of your IDE. For example, there might be a function to **refactor** code. And that includes: renaming fields. So that when you change a name in one place, any usages of that name get updated automatically.

Comment: Bravo! That's precise.

Comment: Thanks!!! You solved my problem!!!!